# Bogus Chrome Installer?

Tags: windows, security, certificate, security-warning

Just a few days ago I tried to download Chrome (using IE 11) to a new Windows 7 system.  I examined the certificate for the Chrome installer (clicking on the highlighted Google Inc. next to Publisher):

Do you want to run this application?

Name: Google Installer

From: dl.google.com

Publisher: Google Inc.

I went to the certification path tab and it showed only "Google Inc" and the Certificate status showed "The issuer of this certificate could not be found."

When I switched to the General tab, it showed under the title Certificate Information that "Windows does not have enough information to verify this certificate." Yet this information was listed:

Issued to: Google Inc.

Issued by: Thawte Code SigningCA-G2

Valid From: 11/9/2011 to 11/9/2014

Under the Details tab, the information looked complete and legitimate to me, with the last line being the sha1 Thumbprint beginning "8a ed 55 2a 13 87 87 0a 53 f5..."

What's going on?

Comment: Run Windows update, Microsoft updates the root CA list (for certificate revocation and such). You will get 'Issuer not found' if the root or intermediate CA in the chain is not installed on your machine.